# Finding the furthest distant centroids to cluster using kmeans

Tags: java, k-means, centroid

Here is an example of how to use kmeans algorithm: http://mnemstudio.org/clustering-k-means-example-1.htm

In this example, the author used as initial centroids "the two individuals furthest apart (using the Euclidean distance measure)", as it was said.

What if I want not two clusters, but 10!
How do I choose the first 10 centroids? 
Is there a way to choose the ten individuals furthest apart?
Or should I use another way to choose them.

PS: I don't think using a randon choice will be good in my case. Also, I've been trying to use the first 10 individuals as centroids, but I am looking for a better way to choose them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply choose the K most further apart entities as initial centroids is rather dangerous. Real-world data sets tend to have outliers, under your approach these would be chosen as initial centroids.

There are many initialization algorithms for K-Means, perhaps you would like to take a look at intelligent K-Means.

Comment: What's the most common way to choose initial centroids?

Comment: I guess most people simply run K-Means a number of times (say 100), and then choose the clustering with the smallest K-Means output.

If your data set is too large for you to run K-Means so many times, I'd suggest Intelligent K-Means.

Comment: My data set has 69 elements to group into 8 clusters. If I choose elements 0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54 and 63 as first centroids, Kmeans reorganizes these centroids 6 times, acording to the mean of the elements of each cluster, then they converge.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to choose initial centroids is to use kmeans++ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B
. with theoretical performance guarantee.

http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf

many python clustering package implements this initialization, such as mlpy, scipy KMeans. but I don't know about JAVA.